# Start and finish actions in a Long Click in Android

Tags: android

I want to know how can I sense when a long click operation has finished. For an example, I want to capture a sound clip while a long click is happening. So I need to start at the beginning of the long click and end recording at the end of the long click.  I want to know how to do the end part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Button myclick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myclick);

    myclick.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.v("tag", "ACTION_UP  end record");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.v("tag", "ACTION_DOWN  start record");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hi，I think this code can help u。

Answer (score 0):

instead of making it a long click...go ahead and create a touchlistener that starts up a timer when you hold onto it for longer than say 2000ms and then does a certain action along with a short vibration if you want (to simulate a long click)